# Не работает route в laravel

Tags: laravel

Всем привет- у меня не хочет работать роут в laravel. Буду признателен любой помощи.

Здесь я вызываю:

```
  <a href="{{ url('/agent-employee/'.$agent->ORG_ID) }}" class=""><button class="btn btn-danger">Сотрудники агента</button></a>
```

а это роут:

```
  Route::get('/agent-employee/{$id}',function ($id) {
          $employee  = DB::select('SELECT AGENT_MAIL.*, S_ORG.ORG_NAME FROM AGENT_MAIL INNER JOIN S_ORG ON (AGENT_MAIL.REF_ORG=S_ORG.ORG_ID) WHERE S_ORG.ORG_ID='.$id.'');
          return view('agent-employee',['employees' => $employee]);
        });
```

При нажатие на кнопку выходит 404 ошибка.

Comment: `/agent-employee/{id}`

Comment: Спасибо) Очень помогли!